# Array return elements where values falls between other values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have an array `[{lowlimit: 0, highlimit 100}, {lowlimit: 201, highlimit: 300}]`

a new element `{lowlimit: 301, highlimit: 400}` or `{lowlimit: 101, highlimit: 150}` should be accepted

but an element like `{lowlimit: 50, highlimit: 80}` or `{lowlimit: 50, highlimit: 250}` should not be accepted as it is within one of the existing ones or overlapping the existing ranges

Any suggestion how to check that in javascript or typescript?

Comment: 1. Loop through array
2. Check if new item overlaps.
3. Add to array if it doesn't

Comment: 3. write your own code

Comment: 4.post question here after you have written your code and you still got problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can add any values. Then you need to get unique value  instead of while adding. like this below way.

```js
 

var a = [{lowlimit: 0, highlimit : 100}, {lowlimit: 201, highlimit:300}, 
     {lowlimit: 50, highlimit: 300}, {lowlimit: 50, highlimit: 300}];

var elementId = [];

var newArr = a.filter(function(el, index){
if (elementId.indexOf(el.lowlimit) === -1) {
    elementId.push(el.lowlimit);
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow some steps:

1. Loop through array.
2. check if new item is **inBetween** the range. (I wrote a function for you, check it below, you can use that to check if values are in between the specified range or not.)
3. Add to array if above check returns false. (or do whatever you want).

Please use the function below inside the loop where you're iterating through your array.

```
function _isBetweenRange(a, b){
    var aLowLimit = a.lowlimit;
  var aHighLimit = a.highlimit;
  var bLowLimit = b.lowlimit;
  var bHighLimit = b.highlimit;
  if(bLowLimit >= aLowLimit && bHighLimit <= aHighLimit){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the fiddle where you can see the code in action.
https://jsfiddle.net/startsco/bg5tuqfh/1/

Answer (score 0):

In the following snippet: `shouldpush()` tests whether or not an `object` should be `pushed` to an `array` (given your rules).

`shouldpush()` `returns` the `resulting` `array` (in order) in the form `[bool, newarray]`.

You can collect the `result` like so: `const [push, newarray] = shouldpush(array, object)`

```js
// Array.
const array = [{lowlimit: 0, highlimit: 100}, {lowlimit: 201, highlimit: 300}]

// Should Push.
const shouldpush = (array, object) => {

  const length = array.length

  for (let i = 0; i <= (length-1); i ++) {

    // Comps.
    const pre = array[i] || false
    const post = array[i+1] || false

    // Cases:
    
    // Length(1) AND Fit Above (Extreme Edge Case).
    if ((length == 1) && (pre.highlimit < object.lowlimit)) return [true, [...array, object]]
    
    // First Fit (Below).
    const atfirst = (i == 0) // At First Index.
    const firstfit = (atfirst && (pre.lowlimit > object.highlimit)) // First Fit.
    if (firstfit) return [true, [object, ...array]] // True.
    
    // Normal Fit.
    const lowfit = (object.lowlimit > pre.highlimit) // Standard Low.
    const highfit = (object.highlimit < post.lowlimit) // Standard High.
    if (lowfit && highfit) return [true, [...array.slice(0, i+1), object, ...array.slice(i+1)]]
    
    // Last Fit (Above).
    const atlast = (i == (length - 2)) // At Last Index.
    const lastfit = (atlast && (post.highlimit < object.lowlimit)) // Last Fit.
    if (lastfit) return [true, [...array, object]] // True.
    
    // No Fit.
    if (!lowfit && !highfit) return [false, [...array]] // !Fit (Early Exit).
  }
  
  return [false, [...array]] // !Fit.
}

// Test Objects.
const w = {lowlimit: 301, highlimit: 400} // W.
console.log(shouldpush(array, w)) // True.
const x = {lowlimit: 101, highlimit: 150} // X.
console.log(shouldpush(array, x)) // True.
const y = {lowlimit: 50, highlimit: 80} // Y.
console.log(shouldpush(array, y)) // False.
const z = {lowlimit: 50, highlimit: 250} // Z.
console.log(shouldpush(array, z)) // False.

// Example Retrieval.
const [push, newarray] = shouldpush(array, x)
console.log(push, newarray) // Push. New Array.
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked great, the only problem i see, the loop starts from 1, so if there is only 2 objects in the array, const post is undefined.

Comment: I see what you mean ahah. Not too sure why I started from `i = 1`. Just refactored to start from `0`. Defs a better approach to cover edge cases such as `length == 1`. Thanks for the feedback. See above for the revised solution.